# Validate TextFomField from different widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have 2 widgets, one is the main one with a bunch of other widgets loaded on it. The other is the `TextFormField` that I need to validate.

Main widget:

```
RoundedInputField(
  onChanged: (value) {
    _email = value;
  },
),
RoundedButton(
   text: "LOGIN",
    press: () async {}, // This is the button that should validate the input
);
```

Field widget:

```
class RoundedInputField extends StatefulWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final IconData icon;
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
  const RoundedInputField({
    Key key,
    this.hintText,
    this.icon = Icons.alternate_email,
    this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RoundedInputFieldState createState() => _RoundedInputFieldState();
}

class _RoundedInputFieldState extends State<RoundedInputField> {
  TextEditingController email = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFieldContainer(
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: email,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress, //TextInputType.phone,
        onChanged: widget.onChanged,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Your Email",
          icon: Icon(
            widget.icon,
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
          ),
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
        validator: (value) {
          return Helpers.CheckInput(value);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I validate the input clicking on the other LOGIN widget?

Comment: Use a `Form` widget

Comment: but how can I interact between those 2 widgets?

Comment: You can use a FormKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
...   
 Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                        RoundedInputField(
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            _email = value;
                          },
                        ),
                        RoundedPasswordField(
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            _password = value;
                          },
                        ),
                        RoundedButton(
                          text: "LOGIN",
                          press: () async {}
                        ),
```